# Swift protocol & weak references with class

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}
```

and in a helper class, I have a reference to a protocol variable:

```
class someClass {
    var delegate: SomeProtocol? 
}
```

because `SomeProtocol` isn't marked with `: class`, it's assumed that `delegate` can be anything and in the case of value types (structs and enums) there's no need for `weak var` because value types can't create strong references. In fact, the compiler doesn't allow `weak var` on anything but class types.

However, nothing stops you from setting a class as the delegate and if the protocol isn't marked with `: class` (as `SomeProtocol is),`weak var` can't be used and that creates a retain cycle.

```
class MyClass: NSObject, SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething() { }
}

struct MyStruct: SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething() { }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
let myStruct = MyStruct()
someClass.delegate = myStruct 
// After myStruct gets assigned to the delegate, do the delegate and the struct refer to the same instance or does the struct get copied?D

let myClass = MyClass()
someClass.delegate = myClass // can't use weak var so myClass is retained
```

Given the above example, in the case of using delegates and datasource, shouldn't `: class` always be used? Basically any protocol that is used to maintain a reference should always be restricted to class objects right?

Comment: I believe only the delegate class/struct holds a weak reference to the delegator, not the delegator holding a weak reference to the delegate.

Comment: I thought so too but I found out when building a `UICollectionView` helper class with a reference to a protocol that wasn't marked class where the reference was to a `UIViewController`. Because the protocol wasn't a class one, the property couldn't be `weak` and was never being deallocated.

Comment: Value types can create strong references. You just cannot create weak reference to value types.

Comment: That can't be right because aren't value types copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. If you a are trying to break retain cycle with weak reference, you have to use classes because `weak` modifier works only with reference types (classes).

Comment: You could, alternatively, break the retain cycle by setting `delegate = nil` in the `deinit()` method

Comment: No, you can't, just because `deinit` method will not be called because of retain cycle.

Comment: I'll clarify in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

`: class` is the preferred approach most of the time. As an alternative answer, though, you can set `delegate = nil` in the `deinit` method of the parent object.

For example, say the parent object is an `NSOperation` subclass that has a `SomeClass` property, and this property has a delegate that implements `SomeProtocol`:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

class SomeClass {
    var delegate: SomeProtocol?
}

class CustomOperation: NSOperation {
    let foo: SomeClass
}
```

We'll make a class that implements the protocol too:

```
class SomeProtocolImplementation: SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Hi!")
    }
}
```

Now we can assign `foo` in `init()`:

```
class CustomOperation: NSOperation {
    let foo: SomeClass

    override init() {
        foo = SomeClass()
        foo.delegate = SomeProtocolImplementation()
        super.init()
    }
}
```

This creates a retain cycle. However, consider this `deinit` method:

```
    deinit {
        foo.delegate = nil
    }
```

Now, whenever `CustomOperation` will be deallocated, `foo.delegate` will be set to `nil`, breaking the retain cycle. Then when the autorelease pool drains at the end of the run loop, both `SomeClass` and `SomeProtocolImplementation` will be deallocated.

Comment: The problem with this is your setup doesn't create a retain cycle in the first place. Your `CustomOperation` instance has a strong reference to a `SomeClass` instance, which has a strong reference to a `SomeProtocolImplementation` instance. That's a linear line, with no cycles – therefore no retain cycle. The way most delegate setups work is (in your case) `foo.delegate = self`, where `self` conforms to `SomeProtocol`. In that case, there's no avoiding the retain cycle through using `deinit`, as both the delegate and delegator will keep each other alive.